# I am having issues with a wave spawner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a Tower Defence game and I need a wave spawner. I tried to use `Brackeys Wave spawner` but it only supports one type of enemy per wave and I tried to make one myself like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class WaveContent
{
    public Transform enemy;
    public int count;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Wave
{
    public string Name;
    public WaveContent[] Enemy;
    public float Rate = 5f;
}
```

instead of this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Wave
{
    public string name;
    public Transform enemy;
    public int count;
    public float rate;
}
```

This is the code from the 40min Brackeys video

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class WaveSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

```
public enum SpawnState { SPAWNING, WAITING, COUNTING };

[System.Serializable]
public class Wave
{
    public string name;
    public Transform enemy;
    public int count;
    public float rate;
}

public Wave[] waves;
private int nextWave = 0;
public int NextWave
{
    get { return nextWave + 1; }
}

public Transform[] spawnPoints;

public float timeBetweenWaves = 5f;
private float waveCountdown;
public float WaveCountdown
{
    get { return waveCountdown; }
}

private float searchCountdown = 1f;

private SpawnState state = SpawnState.COUNTING;
public SpawnState State
{
    get { return state; }
}

void Start()
{
    if (spawnPoints.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No spawn points referenced.");
    }

    waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves;
}

void Update()
{
    if (state == SpawnState.WAITING)
    {
        state = SpawnState.COUNTING;
        /*if (!EnemyIsAlive())
        {
            WaveCompleted();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }*/
    }

    if (waveCountdown <= 0)
    {
        if (state != SpawnState.SPAWNING)
        {
            StartCoroutine( SpawnWave ( waves[nextWave] ) );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        waveCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

void WaveCompleted()
{
    Debug.Log("Wave Completed!");

    state = SpawnState.COUNTING;
    waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves;

    if (nextWave + 1 > waves.Length - 1)
    {
        nextWave = 0;
        Debug.Log("ALL WAVES COMPLETE! Looping...");
    }
    else
    {
        nextWave++;
    }
}

bool EnemyIsAlive()
{
    searchCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (searchCountdown <= 0f)
    {
        searchCountdown = 1f;
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy") == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

IEnumerator SpawnWave(Wave _wave)
{
    Debug.Log("Spawning Wave: " + _wave.name);
    state = SpawnState.SPAWNING;

    for (int i = 0; i < _wave.count; i++)
    {
        SpawnEnemy(_wave.enemy);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1f/_wave.rate );
    }

    state = SpawnState.WAITING;

    yield break;
}

void SpawnEnemy(Transform _enemy)
{
    Debug.Log("Spawning Enemy: " + _enemy.name);

    Transform _sp = spawnPoints[ Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length) ];
    Instantiate(_enemy, _sp.position, _sp.rotation);
}
```

}

And I need to add this to the code to get what I am expecting

```
[System.Serializable]
public class WaveContent
{
    public Transform enemy;
    public int count;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Wave
{
    public string Name;
    public WaveContent[] Enemy;
    public float Rate = 5f;
}
```

But I was not able to, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Dev

Comment: `But I was not able to`, It's not clear what your issue is

Comment: Brackeys code only allows me to spawn one type of enemy per wave like 5 of enemy one but i need like 3 enemy 1's and 2 enemy 2's and like that

Comment: and I don't Know how to do it

Comment: @Devxdprogamer Please tell more. This question is unclear. You need to add more code about spawning the enemies and etc. How do you spawn enemies? Can you show your code and what do you mean about **I was not able to**?

Comment: I need an Wave Spawner For my tower defence game and I thought to use brackeys two part Wave Spawner which is this : (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vrld13ypX_I&t=3s)

Comment: The Code in this Video only allows to spawn 1 type of enemy per wave

Comment: but In my tower Defence Game there is more than 30 or 40 different types of enemies

Comment: and I need code to do this

Comment: Like spawn 3 of enemy3, 4 of enemy 1, etc

Comment: @Devxdprogamer Sorry, we can't go to YouTube and watch the entire video to solve the problem. For StackOverflow, this question is unclear and must be edited and add some descriptions and codes.

Comment: @Devxdprogamer, let me know if my answer below does not facilitate what you're looking to do and I'd be happy to try and assist you further.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the existing comments, I think you really only need one additional edit within the SpawnWave code to achieve what you are looking for - Add a foreach loop to loop through each Wave Contents object and spawn the appropriate number and type of enemy

Given your updated objects, with one update to a field name for clarity

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class WaveContent
    {
        public Transform enemy;
        public int count;
    }
    
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Wave
    {
        public string Name;
        public WaveContent[] WaveContents;
        public float Rate = 5f;
    }
```

Then you just need to loop through the array of WaveContent and call SpawnEnemy for each one, using the WaveContent.Count for the inner loop.

```
    IEnumerator SpawnWave(Wave _wave)
    {
        Debug.Log("Spawning Wave: " + _wave.name);
        state = SpawnState.SPAWNING;
    
        // Loop through your Wave Contents
        foreach (var waveContent in Wave.WaveContents)
        {
            // Spawn the number and type of enemy for each content object
            for (int i = 0; i < waveContent.count; i++)
            {
                SpawnEnemy(waveContent.enemy);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / _wave.rate);
            }
        }
    
        state = SpawnState.WAITING;
    
        yield break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at his code, there will be those lines of code :

```
IEnumerator SpawnWave(Wave _wave)
{
    state = SpawnState.SPAWNING;

    for (int i = 0; i < wave.count; i++)
    {
        SpawnEnemy(_wave.enemy);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1f/_wave.rate );
    }

    state = SpawnState.WAITING;

    yield break;
}
```

And also those lines of code :

```
void SpawnEnemy(Transform _enemy)
{
     Debug.Log("Spawning Enemy: " + _enemy.name);

     Transform sp = spawnPoints[ Randon.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length) ];
     Instantiate(_enemy, _sp.position, _sp.rotation);
}
```

So what is the problem, the problem is that the `SpawnEnemy()` method is using only one type of enemies each wave, using _enemy from class Wave which is in `[System.Serializable]`, so my idea is that we will make another class Wave, same same as his code :

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Wave
{
    public string name;
    public Transform[] enemies;
    public int count;
    public float rate;
}
```

And change a little bit in `SpawnEnemy()` method, which I will add `Random.Rage()` to choose a different transform ( or we can say enemy )

```
void SpawnEnemy(Transform[] _enemies)
{
     Debug.Log("Spawning Enemy: " + _enemy.name);
     int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, _enemies.Count());
     Transform sp = spawnPoints[ Randon.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length) ];
     Instantiate(_enemies[randomIndex], _sp.position, _sp.rotation);
}
```

If having any trouble when doing, just comment below, yeah

Comment: The count is constant in the code you have, I want different amounts of different enemies thats the reason I have this

Comment: each wave you will be spawning numbers of enemies which depends on the number of  Wave.count. Change that and you will be able to edit it

Comment: I can change that for each wave but I want to change that for each type of enemy,

Comment: the more you get, the harder it got. You can just change wave,count in the `SpawnWave()` method like what you need, that is all

Comment: OK thanks, But I am expecting like this 
So start with the first thing in the Enemies array, could put it in a for loop. Then when you have the Enemies object, spawn the amount you want, then continue with the next Enemies array.

Comment: In my code, there will be random number of all enemies in all wave, so you dont need to worry, if you want to adjust more, it will be very complicated

Comment: I want to have control over what enemies i am going to spawn i don't want random

Comment: is there any way to see if an wave is completed spawning

Comment: if you think so, learn about Collections, and you do not use wave. count to loop,you will loop through enemies.